# Qt and chm help file format

Tags: c++, windows, qt, chm

We want to move to Qt for our widget library.  Currently we're using WX and it's compatible with chm.  I can't find anything to suggest that Qt is the same.  We've invested a bunch in CHM tools for the non-technical people to write help files.

Is there a way to view chm with Qt?

If not, is there a reasonably easy path from chm to whatever IS viewable from Qt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plain HTML definitely is. Qt contains a full HTML rendering core (WebKit).

Plus Qt has some internal format (packed HTML, similar to chm) https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq28-qthelp.html

Oh and: http://web.archive.org/web/20120712115053/http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-03/thread00621-0.html explains how to open chm

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using CHM you're probably not writing cross platform code. Just call [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing the chm file full path name as parameter and Windows will open it for you.